# Get Oracle Timestamp value via orm lite in java

Tags: java-time

I have the oracle database field value "11-JUL-16 02.51.45.000000000 AM" for field date_updated.

When I retrieve records via orm lite query and iterate over the result set .. I get the data in this format "2016-7-11.2.51. 45. 0" where the java pojo object mapping field is of type String.

Aim is to update these timestamps after processing them. I am not able to covert the date to update(parse error) or retrieve the date as is.

Searched allover but couldn't find an answer.  I tried changing the pojo field type to Date/Timestamp(sql) but couldn't get it to work.  Any Help would really appreciate ..

Comment: " I am not able to covert the date to update(parse error) or retrieve the date as is." - What is your parse error? What exactly have you tried (code)?

Comment: It worked Thanks much for looking into it... 
    //Input String : 2016-7-11.2.51. 45. 0    public static String getPSTDate(String date){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd.HH.mm.ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfAmerica = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");
    TimeZone tzInAmerica = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");
    sdfAmerica.setTimeZone(tzInAmerica);
    Date dateInAmerica = null;
    try {
    dateInAmerica = formatter.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    return(sdfAmerica.format(dateInAmerica)); 
    }